# Compare two excel file vba

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a VBA code where I can compare data from two different excel files and add output in the third excel File.

File can contains N number of columns and N number of rows it has to validate.

1. I got a code to compare 2 sheets but I need output like below.
   (this vba code will open the excel file to read data)
   [Output of data after comparing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQAoV.png)

> ```
> Sub Compare()
>
> Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
>
> Set objWorkbook1 = Workbooks.Open("F:\Learning\Book1.xlsx")
> Set objWorkbook2 = Workbooks.Open("F:\Learning\Book2.xlsx")
>
> Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook1.Worksheets(1)
> Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)
>
>
> Set WorkRng1 = objWorksheet1.UsedRange
> Set WorkRng2 = objWorksheet2.UsedRange
>
> For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
>     Rng1.Value = Rng1.Value
>     For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
>         If Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value Then
>             
>             
>
>             Exit For
>         End If
>     Next
> Next
>
>
> End Sub
> ```

Output requried like this

> ```
> Name_Book1    | Name_Book2 |  Compare |   Amount_book1 |  Amount_book2|   Compare 
> Store_1       | Store_1    | Pass     | 362            | 420           | Fail
> Store_2       | Store_2    | Pass     | 400            | 360           |Fail
> Store_3       | Store_3    | Pass     | 922            | 520           | Fail
> Store_4       | Store_4    | Pass     | 600            | 320           | Fail
> Store_5       | Store_5    | Pass     | 400            | 400           | Pass
> ```

2. Other code doesn't open the file but i need to compare data and get the output like above.

[Excel File 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12v-pb8nKbknDPVg950uoFOPRPhNX6KCxoYXE_820mGI/edit?usp=sharing) | [Excel File 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13X3J5jp1OkWQScjuyrXLl6006dXhBcdClKdq8C9tc1o/edit?usp=sharing) | [Output file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GKvZjiwpEwcs8ac9JUCqPuuz2CvtW9G_2jVRHV4xElk/edit?usp=sharing)

> Sub GetDataFromSingleCell(cell As String)
>
> ```
> Dim srcCN As Object ' ADODB.Connection
> Dim srcRS As Object ' ADODB.Recordset
>
> Set srcCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
> Set srcRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
>
> srcCN.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
>             "Data Source=" & CStr("F:\Learning\Book1.xlsx") & _
>             ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;"";"
>
> srcRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$" & cell & ":" & cell & "];", srcCN, 3, 1  'adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
>
> srctxt = srcRS.Fields(0).Value
>
> Dim trgCN As Object ' ADODB.Connection
> Dim trgRS As Object ' ADODB.Recordset
>
> Set trgCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
> Set trgRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
>
> trgCN.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
>             "Data Source=" & CStr("F:\Learning\Book2.xlsx") & _
>             ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;"";"
>
> trgRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$" & cell & ":" & cell & "];", trgCN, 3, 1  'adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
>
> trgtxt = trgRS.Fields(0).Value
>
> If srctxt = trgtxt Then
>     Sheet1.Cells(1, 2) = "Passed"
> Else
>     Sheet1.Cells(1, 2) = "Failed"
> End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

Output file contains VBA code for references use.

Maybe reading a txt file same as excel file like above will be good.

Comment: Side note: [Excel comes with an add-in pre-installed that can compare two workbooks in a similar fashion](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compare-workbooks-using-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42).

Comment: Because of the huge amount of data, not able to open the excel file. so I required a VBA code that can help me.

Comment: You need to provide more detail about exactly how you want to compare the two files.  Are they both structured the same way? Are the rows in the same order and do both files contain the same amount of data?  Why is one comparison "Pass" and the other "TRUE/FALSE" ?  There's a lot of necessary info missing here.

Comment: Yes. Structured and rows will be in the same order. Thanks, updated those True/False things.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

You will need a sheet named "Compare" in the workbook where the code is running.

```vb
Sub Compare()

    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, arr1, arr2, arrOut
    Dim rw As Long, col As Long, c As Long, v1, v2
    
    'open workbooks and assign ranges  
    Set Rng1 = Workbooks.Open("F:\Learning\Book1.xlsx").Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    Set Rng2 = Workbooks.Open("F:\Learning\Book2.xlsx").Worksheets(1).UsedRange
   
    'check ranges are comparable 
    If Rng1.Rows.Count <> Rng2.Rows.Count Or _
       Rng1.Columns.Count <> Rng2.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox "Ranges are different sizes!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'faster to read from arrays...
    arr1 = Rng1.Value
    arr2 = Rng2.Value
    'size array for output (need 3 output columns per input column)
    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arr1, 1), 1 To 3 * UBound(arr1, 2))
    
    For rw = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
        c = 1 'start column position in output array
        For col = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
            v1 = arr1(rw, col)
            v2 = arr2(rw, col)
            If rw = 1 Then
                'column headers here...
                arrOut(rw, c) = v1 & "_book1"
                arrOut(rw, c + 1) = v2 & "_book2"
                arrOut(rw, c + 2) = "Compare"
            Else
                'column values comparison
                arrOut(rw, c) = v1
                arrOut(rw, c + 1) = v2
                arrOut(rw, c + 2) = IIf(v1 = v2, "Pass", "Fail")
            End If
            c = c + 3
        Next col
    Next rw
    
    'put result array on worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compare")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrOut, 1), UBound(arrOut, 2)).Value = arrOut
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: if I have 30000 thousand rows, but I want to validate only 10000 thousand rows. can you guide me on where should I add it? @Tim Williams

Comment: above logic can we apply for the code without opening the excel files? @tim-williams

Comment: Instead of `For rw = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)` use `For rw = 1 To 10000`  No this code would require you to open the files.

Comment: Is there any way like above without opening the excel files, the above task should be done?

Comment: If I just want to add only failed columns to output excel, what code do I need to update? @Tim Williams

Comment: Why don't you give it a try? However if you only want to output the differences then you might want to change the format of your output table

Comment: The output should be the same but only failed data should be there that it, trying but new to VBA code totally.

Comment: And want to add row_number to A1 columns for the failed records will start from B1 column. trying from my end not getting any result. @tim-williams

Comment: When I am trying to open a large file that contains  1000000 Sales Records. VBA code is opening the first file but the second file is not opening.                                            If Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:20")) Then
        Set Rng2 = Workbooks.Open(secondfile, True, True).Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    End If

Comment: If you have that much data then Excel may not be the best tool for the job.

Comment: @KViswanathaReddy You can "accept" an answer by clicking the tick mark green beside the answer. To me it seems this answer addresses your question as good as Excel can.